# Converting JSON string to Map with custom types

Tags: java, json, jackson

My JSON string is like this:

```
{
    "100": {
        "mode": 100,
        "enabled": true,
        "value": "someString"
    },
    "101": {
        "mode": 101,
        "enabled": false,
        "value": "someString"
    }
}
```

I have a class actually

```
class Mode {

    @JsonProperty("mode")
    long mode;

    @JsonProperty("enabled")
    boolean enabled;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    String value;

}
```

I tried

```
objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```

But its generic map and also the numbers are converted to `Integer` types not `Long`. Using `Mode` in place of `Map` above throws exception.

1. How to get `Long` in generic `Map`?
2. And, how can I get a `Map<String, Mode>` out of the json string?

I have got jackson library in my projects maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your Key is `String` . It will work for you .

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Mode>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Mode>>() {};
Map<String,Mode> map = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,typeRef);
```

**Updated :**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Mode {

  @JsonProperty("mode")
  long mode;

  @JsonProperty("enabled")
  boolean enabled;

  @JsonProperty("value")
  String value;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Mode{" +
        "mode=" + mode +
        ", enabled=" + enabled +
        ", value='" + value + '\'' +
        '}';
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String json = "{\n"
        + "    \"100\": {\n"
        + "        \"mode\": 100,\n"
        + "        \"enabled\": true,\n"
        + "        \"value\": \"someString\"\n"
        + "    },\n"
        + "    \"101\": {\n"
        + "        \"mode\": 101,\n"
        + "        \"enabled\": false,\n"
        + "        \"value\": \"someString\"\n"
        + "    }\n"
        + "}";

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, Mode>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Mode>>() {
    };
    Map<String, Mode> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    map.entrySet().forEach(entry-> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " +entry.getValue() ));
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
100 : Mode{mode=100, enabled=true, value='someString'}
101 : Mode{mode=101, enabled=false, value='someString'}
```

Comment: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of "com.xyz.Mode" (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"1001":{"mode":9223372036854775807,"enabled":true,"value":8}}"; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["1001"])`

Comment: Thanks Khalid for looking. As I said, I am getting above exception.

Comment: @xploreraj see Updated code. It work perfectly fine. ans i also show the output after reading Json.

Comment: Thanks Khalid. I was creating the map and then using typeref, thats why I think I got the error. Your solutions works. As regards to Integer to Long, I figured out if number is out of range for int, its automatically converted into Long by jackson.